# ActiveMQ Artemis: Use Plain TCP and TLS in parallel

Tags: cluster, activemq

In ActiveMQ Artemis, when acceptors and connectors are both configured, we see clients connecting to the TCP as well as the TLS port. How can we control that a client stays on its initial connection protocol? I.e., a client connecting via TLS should continue to use TLS, while TLS incapable clients should stick to TCP.

```xml
        <connectors>
          <connector name="artemis">tcp://${ipv4addr}:61616?sslEnabled=false</connector>
          <connector name="artemis-tls">tcp://${ipv4addr}:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;useEpoll=true;sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=trusts
tore.jks;trustStorePassword=${keyStorePassword}</connector>
        </connectors>

        <acceptors>
          <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;connectionsAllowed=10000</acceptor>
          <acceptor name="artemis-tls">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=COR
E,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=keystore.jks;keyStorePasswor
d=${keyStorePassword};enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2</acceptor>
        </acceptors>

        <broadcast-groups>
          <broadcast-group name="cluster-broadcast-group">
            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
            <jgroups-file>jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <connector-ref>artemis-tls</connector-ref>
          </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>

        <discovery-groups>
          <discovery-group name="cluster-discovery-group">
            <jgroups-file>jgroups.xml</jgroups-file>
            <jgroups-channel>active_broadcast_channel</jgroups-channel>
            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
          </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>

        <cluster-connections>
          <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
            <connector-ref>artemis-tls</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="cluster-discovery-group"/>
          </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
```